# How to track pageviews without thrashing the MySQL DB

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to track pageviews in MySQL DB using the following query:

`"UPDATE $table SET pageviews = pageviews + 1 WHERE page_id = 1"`

This is fine for low to moderate traffic. However, under high traffic, constant writes to the DB would result in high read/write contention and eventually bring down the DB.

I have read several QA's here on Stackoverflow and elsewhere, where MongoDB is suggested as an alternative. However, that choice ain't available and I must stick to MySQL. Furthermore, I do not have control over the Engine — MyISAM or InnoDB (InnoDB performs better due to row based locking instead of table, as in case of MyISAM).

Considering the above scenario, what's the best posible method to track pageviews without thrashing the DB (in DB or something else)? I would really appreciate an answer that provides code fragments as a starting point (if posible).

BTW, I am using PHP.

Update:
@fire has a good solution here. However, it requires use of memcache. I am, looking at something that could be easily implemented without requiring specific infra. This is for a module that could virtually be used in different hosting environments. On a second thought things that comes to my mind are some sort of cookie or file log based implementation. I am not sure how such implementation would work in practice. Any further inputs are really welcome.

Comment: If you dont want to trash **your** DB, then just use [Google Anlaytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/)

Comment: @Dainas Exactlty what I was going to say..

Comment: @DainisAbols I missed specifying this. GA is not an option. This is needed for "simple" in app analytics.

Comment: With so many limitations, is it a reasonable assumption that this is a high traffic situation? It would seem like the simple UPDATE would work for a pretty good range of hit frequency, and if it becomes a problem, switch over to GA.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I would use memcached to store the count, and then sync it with the database on a cron...

```
// Increment
$page_id = 1;
$memcache = new Memcache();
$memcache->connect('localhost', 11211);

if (!$memcache->get('page_' . $page_id)) {
    $memcache->set('page_' . $page_id, 1);
}
else {
    $memcache->increment('page_' . $page_id, 1);
}

// Cron
if ($pageviews = $memcache->get('page_' . $page_id)) {
    $sql = "UPDATE pages SET pageviews = pageviews + " . $pageviews . " WHERE page_id = " . $page_id;
    mysql_query($sql);
    $memcache->delete('page_' . $page_id);
}
```

Comment: This is great until you lose power or have to reboot the system.

Comment: This looks to be promising solution. I'll look into this further.

Comment: @tadman it's a suitable trade-off, if the database got overloaded you wouldn't be able to write to it anyways!

Comment: I do something similar, but with redis.

Answer (score 1):

I'd consider gathering raw hits with the fastest writing engine you have available:

```
INSERT INTO hits (page_id, hit_date) VALUES (:page_id, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

... and then running a periodical process, possibly a cron command line script, that would count and store the page count summary you need in an hourly or daily basis:

```
INSERT INTO daily_stats (page_id, num_hits, day)
SELECT page_id, SUM(hit_id)
FROM hits
WHERE hit_date='2012-11-29'
GROUP BY page_id
```

(Queries are mere examples, tweak to your needs)

Another typical solution is good old log parsing, feeding a script like AWStats with your web server's logs.

**Clarification:** My first suggestion is fairly similar to [@fire's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13628885/13508) but I didn't get into storage details. The key point is to delay heavy processing and just the minimum amount of raw info in the fastest way.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are considering the fact that inserts would be faster than updates. However, an insert on every page load on a high traffic site would still be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified the read or write rate to this table. MySQL can usually keep up quite well if you keep the indexing to an absolute minimum and the row size small. A table with a page ID and a counter column should be very fast most of the time.

InnoDB should be fine as well. MyISAM is liable to explode in the worst possible way if the system crashes or loses power during heavy write activity, it's not journaled and can't always be recovered. InnoDB is much more robust.

To get maximum performance from InnoDB, you'll want to tune your server according to the [standard guidelines](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-innodb.html) and benchmark it aggressively to be sure you got it right. Each OS has its quirks. Sometimes you can be missing out on a factor of two performance increase by not having the right setting.

If your tracking database is small, you might want to create an instance backed by a RAM disk and replicate it to another server with a regular HD. Since you're expecting extremely high write activity, if you can endure a small loss of data in the worst possible situation like a system crash, you could simply `mysqldump` this database periodically to snapshot it. Dumping a memory-backed database with even a million rows should take only a minute and wouldn't interrupt writes due to MVCC.

Comment: Well, I don't have the choice of choosing the engine. My module would be deployed into different environments and the DB infra is not a choice I make. Though you are correct in stating that InnoDB would outperform MyISAM for this particular use.

Comment: Using MyISAM is always risky and usually misguided. I have no idea why anyone would force that on you other than to make your life difficult.