# Best Way To Track Page Views and store in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am currently developing an article driven site and would like to know the best way to track page hits so I can display something along the lines of "Most Viewed" or "Most Popular Articles". I display my articles through a $_GET on a single PHP page (e.g article.php?id=2). I read somewhere that an INSERT INTO was the way to go and I tried to do:

```
$page_views = $conn->query("INSERT INTO blog_posts (views) VALUES (views = views+1");
```

Alas, this did not work.

In summary I want to be able to:

- Add 1 to the number of page views on an specific id for each time someone lands on the page (e.g articles.php?id=3) not just articles.php

Thanks in advance.
(Sorry if I haven't made this clear enough. If you want anything clarifying just ask.)

Comment: i would say the best way is to not do it your self and use google analytics

Comment: How to track pageviews without thrashing the MySQL DB - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13628627/how-to-track-pageviews-without-thrashing-the-mysql-db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try with update statement:

```
"UPDATE blog_posts SET views = views+1 WHERE id = $id"
```

Your insert statement will add a new row in the database, what probably is not what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Do you intend to keep a separate table for the counts?  If so,

```
|page_views   |
|blog_id|count|
+-------+-----+
|  1    | 12  |
|  2    | 33  |
```

with blog_id being a primay key with unique enforced

you could use on duplicate key to create a row if it doesn't exist and update the count if it does

```
("INSERT INTO page_views (blog_id,count) VALUES ($blog_id,1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE count = count + 1")
```

Comment: also, standard caveat, if the blog_id came from the user's browser, i.e. in a get string or post data, make sure you use something like mysqli_real_escape_string to help protect yourself from sql injection

Answer (score 0):

Use an update query to increment the counter.

```
UPDATE blog_posts SET views = views+1 WHERE id = 'SOME NUMBER'
```

Where your each row in the `blog_posts` table has a numberic `views` field and an `id`.

SQL Fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0915b/1